# Send Attachments mail Windows phone 8 C sharp

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I 'm building an application with share fonction on it. I would like to send a picture by mail. I try with EmailComposeTask but i can't add attachment. 
I know that there is the library MailMessage, but I want to go through the mail application of the phone.

I think for an another solution: upload the image on skydrive and just put the link in the mail. so here is the second question, how can i upload a photo on skydrive and get backl the link

I really don't understand why we can't send attachment

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to use skydrive api and Live connect sdk

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh243641

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826521.aspx

Comment: Ok thank you but I would like to have a solution for my first question.